# Setting page titles as attribute values with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm wondering if anyone knows to how to set a page's title to an attribute.

Was thinking something along the lines of:

```
<% content_for :title, "Museum | '@gallery.name'" %>
```

But I cant figure out what to wrap @gallery.name in, if this is even the  right approach.

It's probably a really simple question, but I seem to be stumped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe?

`<% content_for :title do %>
  (@gallery && @gallery.name) || 'Museum'
<% end %>`

of course `yield :title` somwewhere is required

credits to @Clark

if the text should be Museum | foobar if @gallery name exists then instead of 
`(@gallery && @gallery.name) || 'Museum'` it should be 
`"Museum | #{@gallery && @gallery.name}` (in case @gallery is always guaranteed to be defined even simplier `"Museum | #{@gallery.name}"` (remember to use double `"` not `'`).

Comment: I think he wanted to add the gallery name, like `"Museum | #{@gallery.name}"`

Comment: Ahhhhh of course, you are totally right @clark. Feel free to post an answer!

Comment: @chris You can go ahead and accept, dj's answer, he provided a much more in depth explanation, to also help protect against errors. As an additional note, never use the `#{}` when makaing SQL queries, as it is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Good point!!! Thanks for the reminder! It should be okay in this case as there is no interaction between users and the DB, correct?

Comment: Minor thing, I would do ``"Museum#{' | ' + @gallery.name if @gallery.present?  }"``, or even better create a helper for this, so that pages that have no @gallery will not have "Museum | " as their title.

Comment: Yup, it's definitely safe in this case, in most it will be.